# Difference in operations of Bus Mastering and Third Party DMA

Tags: driver, linux-device-driver, cpu-architecture, dma

After some digging my understanding on DMA is following -

1) BUS mastering DMA controller resides on the device card.

```
a) does cycle stealing, and takes control of system bus to control transfers. Plz correct.
b) hard-disk controllers and NIC are examples
c) I know of BR and BG signals used to take control of system bus to access memory
```

2) Third party DMA, stays on system board.

```
a) performs burst mode transfers (i am not very firm on this though)
b) uses channels as scatter-gather lists for transfers
c) do not know which devices use them. please help.
d) have no idea on how the DMA accesses memory in this case.
```

Another important item I want to understand is - what is the requirement that makes a device maker to choose one of 1) or 2). 
Also please let me know if my  understanding as mentioned is correct.

Comment: Bus mastering controllers have to be on the motherboard or connected to it (such as PCI controller), such as on board Sata controllers, or PCI slot Sata raid controllers. The controllers need scatter / gather lists (of at least size 1), since the virtual pages are scattered in physical memory. The larger the list, the fewer the number of interrupts needed to update the list during an I/O command. I don't know if any devices use "classic" DMA, but that could be considers as Bus Mastering with a single list element.

Comment: thanks. I have my fundamentals wrong. is scatter-gather used for bus-mastering as well?

Comment: Yes, what appears to be a continuous buffer in virtual memory is a bunch of scattered physical pages, for X86, usually 4096 bytes each. The buffer needs to be locked and translated into a list of physical addresses and lengths. The controller usually has multiple "descriptors", where each "descriptor" has an address and length.

Comment: Please refer to the link for Solaris Drivers - It is saying what I posted in my original question. please let me know, what is wrong with my understanding. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/805-7378/6j6un035t/index.html

Comment: Bus mastering and scatter/gather are orthogonal concepts.  Any DMA controller (e.g. 3rd-party DMA) that has DMA chaining can also do scatter/gather.  Your 1b is incorrect.  Since IDE, the "hard disk controller" is embedded with the drive.  A 'host bus adapter' would have the bus master capability, not a disk controller.  Neither would the typical NIC have bus-master capability.  Both DMA controllers and bus masters use "cycle stealing", and could utilize "burst mode".  You're confusing who/what is in control of the DMA versus how DMA works.

Comment: @sawdust : I agree that disk/NIC controller would not have bus mastering capability, rather I meant to say that the device card has that DMA engine onboard. Let me know if that is also incorrect.

Comment: Bus master is a property of the device connected to the bus, on opposite to 3rd DMA which just does all transactions on device behalf.